# Is there any way to specify that an array contains both parent and child class items

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following hierarchy:

```
interface Cmp {
  guid: string;
}

interface ContainerCmp extends Cmp {
  layout: string;
}
```

Now, I have an array of items that can be either of `Cmp` or `ContainerCmp` type. It means that some items in the array will be missing `layout` property.

Right now typescript doesn't allow me to specify both types for `items`:

```
const items: Cmp[] | ContainerCmp[] = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
  if (isContainerCmp(item)) {
    console.log(item.layout);
  }
});
```

produces an error:

```
Error:(28, 1) TS2349:Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type '{ (callbackfn: (this: void, value: Cmp, index: number, array: Cmp[]) => void): void; 
(callbackfn:...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

So I specify the top most `Cmp` type and use type guards:

```
const items: Cmp[] = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
  if (isContainerCmp(item)) {
    console.log(item.layout);
  }
});

function isContainerCmp(cmp: Cmp | ContainerCmp): cmp is ContainerCmp {
  return (<ContainerCmp>cmp).layout !== undefined;
}
```

I'm wondering if it's the right approach and if there's any other way to specify both types for the array `items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an array that has only `Cmp` or only `ContainerCmp`.

```
const items: Cmp[] | ContainerCmp[] = [];
```

This is an array that has both `Cmp` and `ContainerCmp`.

```
const items: (Cmp | ContainerCmp)[] = [];
// or
const items: Array<Cmp | ContainerCmp> = [];
```

**EDIT:** Added @NitzanTomer suggestion to the answer.

Comment: Or `Array<Cmp | ContainerCmp>`

Comment: thanks, can you add to the answer what @NitzanTomer suggested as well?

Comment: and one more clarification - I'll still have to use type guard, right? otherwise I'm getting the error `Error:(30, 8) TS2339:Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'Cmp | ContainerCmp'`

Comment: Yes, you need the type guard.